# Can Delphi 6 be installed in Windows 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Previously, a few weeks back,
I asked a similar question regarding D6 and Windows 7.
After installing Delphi 6 in another path, it worked.

BUT now,
after upgrading from W7 to Windows 10 it no longer works.

I am prompted to register the software.
I do that, and am told the registration was successful.
Attempting to start again I am told license information
 is invalid or missing.

The program will not start.

What is needed to run D6 in a Windows 10 machine?

Comment: I just install it to its default location and apply a permissive ACL on C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an Howto I've found at ViaSoftThink I've translated it for you

How to:
Don’t install under C:\Programme (x86) use another folder e.g. C:\software_old

After the installation you're forced to register. Whether the registration process was canceled or successful you probably get an error message:

**"License information is invalid or missing Please register"**

Now do the following:

Execute **c:\software_old\Borland\Delphi6\bin\D6RegClean.exe**

After this install Delphi 6 from your CD but this time choose "**repair**"

To use the Help System you need to install WinHlp32.exe Microsoft doesn’t give you an Installation Package but you can download it [here](https://www.viathinksoft.de/download.php?id=186)

If you follow the steps above and still have a registration error pop up there might be that you need to edit the registry at:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi\6.0**

On the right side you'll find an entry which is called **LM**
Delete that key and try again registering...

Please note: Messing around with the registry can break your system only do it if you know what your doing

Comment: I deleted LM, and it worked. No D6RegClean, no repair.

Comment: No problem its a pleasure

Comment: Yep, just delete the LM key, none of the rest of this answer is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Deletion of LM key, worked for me,

1. Delete key.
2. Reboot.
3. Launch Delphi, choose register later, quit.
4. Launch Delphi again, works OK.

Also, I modified authorization of `c:/programmes/borland/delphi/bin` to total control and `delphi32.exe` compatibility properties to Windows XP and executed as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Delete LM key from Registry]
Restart Delphi and choose register later. 
New LM key will be created and you can continue unregistered
Needed to fix legacy code from 2005